# Asp.net form links

Tags: asp.net

How can I use a link in asp.net as a button. What's the right way to do this? For example with a label I'm doing it like this:

```
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welkom<asp:Label ID="txtWelkom" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></a>
```

And then I set the label to a value that I received from the server for example:

```
txt.Welkom = name;
```

So how can I do this with a link (without seeing the button).
Is this the right way to do it (in asp.net forms)?

Answer (score 0):

You want the LinkButton Control:

On .aspx side

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkWelkom" runat="server"  OnClick="lnkWelkom_OnClick" />
```

Code behind (aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace StackOverflowExamples.WebForms
{
  public partial class _Default : Page
  {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var name = "";
      lnkWelkom.Text = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(name, true);
    }

    protected void lnkWelkom_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Do stuff
    }
  }
}
```